# JS: how to check if file exists in JS or AJAX?

Tags: javascript, file, validation

i want to check if a local file exists, if it not exists i want to run an alert('File not exists!').
I tried something like this :

```js
function isOnline() {
    var xmlPath = "/test/test/myfile.xml"
    var request=new XMLHttpRequest(); 

    request.open("GET",xmlPath,false);
    request.send();

    
    if (request.readyState === 4){
       return true; 
    }else{
        alert('File Away!');
       return false;
    }
}
```

But this dont work.
i cant use PHP or jquery.

Comment: You can't this, you have to use a `server-side` technology.

Comment: AJAX is a javascript communication method for transferring data. Attempting to use it as a file checker (*or* AJAX) doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to get a resource from a server means the file should be publicly accessible through an URL.

When you launch that request with the `XMLHttpRequest` object with `request.send()` that call is asynchronous so checking immediately the `readyState`or `status` it will not assure you the end of the call.

```
function isOnline() {
    var xmlPath = "/test/test/myfile.xml"
    var request=new XMLHttpRequest(); 

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              alert("File was found on URL");
       }else if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 404 ) {
              alert("File away!");
       }
   };
    request.open("GET",xmlPath,false);
    request.send();
}
```

You should subscribe to the status change event and check the values of that change. So beyond checking for the `readyState==4` to get the change to the end of the transaction you should check also for the status code. For example 200 means everything was ok or 404 means the resource was not found.

Check the specification for that codes here:
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html